# Find data for latest Inserted date using linq in c#, mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have This table "CommonData" in my mySql table

[image]

I want to query from c# using linq to find list of "Id" from latest inserted date.
i.e. Here Latest Insert Date is "22-04-2013" , so I should get list of Ids whos insert date is "22-04-2013".

I am using Linq for it.

Some how I am not able to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a subquery retrieving the maximum date, and then filter on this date:

```
var ids = ctx.CommonDatas
             .Where(c => c.InsertDate == 
                               ctx.CommonDatas
                                  .Max(c2 => c2.InsertDate)
                   )
             .Select(c => c.Id);
```

Comment: I would take this `ctx.CommonDatas
                                  .Max(c2 => c2.InsertDate)` out of the `Where`

Comment: Well, yes and no. Yes, it could run the query faster. No,  you are caching the maximum date so you can retrieve asynchronous records (the maximum date could change), and you are hitting the database twice.

Answer (score 0):

simple one might be using **`OrderByDescending`**

```
var result = CommonData.OrderByDescending(c=> c.InsertDate).Select(c => c.Id);
```